# How to call a python function with parameters from a batch file

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, batch-file

I want to call a python function with one or more arguments using a batch file. Is this possible?

Not sure where to start with this one!

Python function code

```py
def my_function(port):
    #Import Serial
     import serial

    # Set COM Port.....
    ser = serial.Serial('COM' + port, 115200, timeout=0, 
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, rtscts=0)

    ser.close()
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=python+command+line+arguments

Comment: I recommend the `argparse` module in the standard library

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myfunc(sys.argv)
```

**EDIT**
Note that the first element of `sys.argv` is your script's name, so if your function is declared this way `myfunc(a, b)` you have to call it like `myfunc(*sys.argv[1:])`. You would also to do some validations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want some more and easy to use functionality. Use click! https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/